# Position Sticky not working on Microsoft Edge 41.*

Tags: css-position, microsoft-edge, sticky, floating-action-button

I've created a little jsfiddle for a Floating Action Button.
It seems to work just fine on iOS, Desktop and Android using Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Explorer and Edge version 40 BUT as soon as I update to Edge version 41 (the latest) it breaks!

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if something changed in the last version of Edge that breaks "position: sticky"?

I've google this issue and checked here too but I don't seem to find an answer ...

Thank you for your time!

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/irith/evpbacfb/3/)**

```css
.fab-overlay {
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}
.fab-overlay .fab-container {
    width: 55px;
    position: sticky;
}
.fab-overlay .fab-container .fab {
    float: right;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text             
  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type       
  and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s 
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
  PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Why do we use it?
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
  readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
  using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution       
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making 
  it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and 
  web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, 
  and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
  their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the 
  like).
  
  What is Lorem Ipsum?
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text             
  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type       
  and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s 
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
  PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Why do we use it?
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
  readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
  using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution       
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making 
  it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and 
  web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, 
  and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
  their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the 
  like).

  What is Lorem Ipsum?
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text             
  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type       
  and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s 
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
  PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Why do we use it?
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
  readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
  using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution       
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making 
  it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and 
  web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, 
  and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
  their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the 
  like).

  What is Lorem Ipsum?
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text             
  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type       
  and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s 
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
  PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Why do we use it?
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
  readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
  using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution       
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making 
  it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and 
  web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, 
  and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
  their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the 
  like).

  What is Lorem Ipsum?
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text             
  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type       
  and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
  only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s 
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
  PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  Why do we use it?
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
  readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of 
  using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution       
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making 
  it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and 
  web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, 
  and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in 
  their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, 
  sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the 
  like).

</div>

<div class="fab-overlay">
 <footer class="footer fab-container">
  <a href="#" class="fab"></a>
 </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by 'it breaks' in greater detail?

Comment: If I delete position:sticky; it seems to behave as it does in Chrome

Comment: @gimg1 'it breaks' meaning it loses the stickiness and also disappears...

Comment: @AlexK. I agree but then it breaks on all the other browsers...

Comment: @MichelaFederico It happens with a page I'm working on as well... I think Edge is behind the others as always, they haven't implemented it correctly yet.